# user review not entering in database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a page to allow users to leave reviews for books.  I have am checking that the fields not empty, the username exists in the users table and the book ID exists in the books table.  If all these things pass then I want to enter the review into the reviews table.

Currently when I fill out the form and submit, I get no output whatsoever, no errors, just a blank screen.

Here is the code:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';
session_start();
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_USERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

$book = $_POST["book_id"];
$username = $_POST["user"];
$review = $_POST["review"];
$rating = $_POST["rating"];

if (empty($book) || empty($username) || empty($review) || empty($rating) ) {
    $error = "Complete all fields";     
}

if ($rating > 5 || $rating < 0) {
    $error =  "Please enter a rating between 1 and 5";
}

if (!isset($error)){
    //no error
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :user");
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $error = "user does not exsist";
}

if (!isset($error)){
    //no error
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT b_id FROM users WHERE b_id = :book_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':book_id', $book);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $error = "Book does not exsist, please enter another ID";
}       

if (!isset($error)) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO reviews (book_id ,username, review, rating) VALUES (:book_id,:user,:review,:rating)';    
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute(array(
        ':book_id' => $book,
        ':user' => $username,
        ':review' => $review,
        ':rating' => $rating    
    ));
} else {
    echo "error occured: ".$error;
    exit();
}
```

I want the checks to be made and the information to be entered in the database, can anyone show me how to do this please?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to generate any output in the event that no errors occurred.  Have you tried checking the `reviews` table to see if any new records have been inserted?

Comment: Yes, its still an empty set.

Comment: Consider using `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` to debug your queries. Add that line after every `prepare` command and share with us the output.

Comment: @stark I took the liberty of editing your question to make the source code better readable.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I enter this code in the three statements and got the folloing output. Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: using PHP print/echo the query and use a SQL browser to test the query and see if you are getting any results.

Comment: Whats the schema for the table? Check the form data converts for SQL properly.

Comment: Now try: After the 2 cases of `$stmt = $dbh->prepare...` write `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());`. After `$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);` write `print_r($query->errorInfo());` **EDIT** Put after the `execute` command

Comment: And you put it after the `execute` line? This is really strange - it means that the queries are valid. If the insert query is valid - it should go to the database. 1) Can it be that you're connecting to the wrong database? 2) Are you absolutely sure that the data isn't being inserted? Maybe the cells are empty but still new rows are being added?

Comment: Sorry I saw your edit after I wrote that! heres what it prints after exexute...`Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 42S22 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'username' in 'field list' )`

Comment: Vaula! There's no field named `username` in your table.

Comment: Oh god how careless! You are right, in the reviews table the username is stored under 'user' not 'username' as it is in the other two tables.  Thank you, should have checked more thoroughly.

Comment: Although now I have a separate problem, the code is not doing the checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error output of the last query it seems that the reviews table doesn't has a `username` field.
Which is also logical - I believe it should be something like `user_id` (as a PK relation).

```
Query 1 Error output: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
Query 2 Error output:  Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
Query 3 Error output:  Array ( [0] => 42S22 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'username' in 'field list' )
```

The query:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO reviews (book_id ,username, review, rating) VALUES (:book_id,:user,:review,:rating)';    
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
```

The error as mentioned is:

```
Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code to the very beginning of your script.  If you cannot connect to the database, you will catch the error and print to the console.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_USERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: There is no error, I am able to connect to the database.

Comment: It is best practice to do this anyway.

Comment: Thanks, i'll use this on the rest of my pages.

Comment: Please notice that this code will only show error in case of problem with connecting to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your error handling as it is cannot work. Let's have a look at an example:

```
if (!isset($error)){
    //no error
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :user");
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $error = "user does not exsist";
}
```

First of all, +1 for using prepared statements with parameter bindings! If I interpret the code correctly, what you **want** this code to do is the following:

1. Check of the user with name `$username` exists
2. Set the `$error` variable to the value `"user does not exist"` when the user does not exists, otherwise leave `$error` undefined.

What your code **actually does** is the following:

1. If no previous error occured (`if(!isset($error))`) select the user with name `$username` and discard the result
2. If a previous error **did occur** (`else`), **do not** check if the user exists, but unconditionally overwrite the `$error` variable.

What you **need to do** is evaluate the result of your query to check if the user actually exists (notice that you currently execute an SQL query, but do not evaluate it's results in any way):

```
$stmt = $dhb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE username = :user");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
$stmt->execute();

$userCount = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if ($userCount == 0) {
    $error = "User does not exist";
}
```

Furthermore, you do not check the success of the final `INSERT` statement. This means that if that last SQL query fails, you will not get any kind of error output.

The easiest way (imho) to add error handling for PDO queries is to configure PDO to throw an exception on an error by setting the *error mode*:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

In that case, each PDO query will throw an exception on an SQL error that you can catch and process in your application:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO reviews (book_id ,username, review, rating) VALUES (:book_id,:user,:review,:rating)';    
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

try {
    $query->execute(array(
        ':book_id' => $book,
        ':user' => $username,
        ':review' => $review,
        ':rating' => $rating    
    ));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Process exception $e as you see fit.
}
```

Comment: Although the main problem is fixed, this did address a secondary problem in my code that i wasn't aware of, this is extremely helpful, thank you!